# RMarkdown with beamer presentation generates ggplot graphs with wrong margins. What should I do?

Tags: pdf-generation, r-markdown, beamer

I'm using RMarkdown with beamer-presentation to generate slides in pdf format. All goes well when I am checking the code results in RStudio. However, when I knit the code, the plots generated get very bad margins and the title gets cut off as you can see in this image:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neylsoncrepalde/neylsoncrepalde.github.io/master/img/bad_graph.png

I have already tried reinstalling rmarkdown, reinstalling R, reinstalling RStudio with no success. I'm running on a 2012 Macbook with MacOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra). I installed R and RStudio with homebrew. This is the code I use.

````r
    ---
    title: "Test of bad margins graphs"
    output: 
      beamer_presentation:
        keep_tex: true
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
    library(ggplot2)
    data("diamonds")
    ```

    ##
    ```{r graph1}
    ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "Diamonds plot", subtitle = "A nice scatterplot with 
    ggplot2")
    ```
````

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you can use https://sebastiansauer.github.io/figure_sizing_knitr/ to change the width and height of the plot? (just a guess)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @samcarter. I have already tried setting fig.width and fig.height with no success. I'm stuck with the same problem. Cheers.

Comment: I just tested your code in https://rstudio.cloud/project/675512 and cannot reproduce the cutoff title. Maybe some version problem?